# My android app crashes on Android 10 after upgrading the compileSdkVersion to 29

Tags: android, android-10.0

My android app crashes on **Android 10** after upgrading the **compileSdkVersion to 29**

**This is the crash message:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:163)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getTargetSdk(FragmentManager.java:2975)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2964)
        at android.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:88)
        at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:7710)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 

E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.epicsyst.ibc/com.epicsyst.ibc.view.activities.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:163)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getTargetSdk(FragmentManager.java:2975)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2964)
        at android.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:88)
        at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:7710)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3224)
```

I searched the error message in Google and it gave me this on Github:
https://github.com/takahirom/DownloadableCalligraphy/pull/4/commits/3707383200749b385cc77adb2bb1aaf447420d62 but i couldn't relate!!

**This is the activity xml file**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.activities.Splash">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The java file**

```
package com.****.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.******.R;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            applyAppFont();
        }

        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
            super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
        }

        /**
         * This method to apply custom font in activity using third-party library.
         */
        private void applyAppFont() {
            CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(
                    new CalligraphyConfig.Builder().setDefaultFontPath("fonts/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:` Your app does not have to crash if you catch the exception or check for null before use. Make your app robust!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's a knowed issue for the Calligraphy library : https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/475

Could you try to migrate to the Caliligraphy 3 : https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy ?